# Comparison on different classes

Tags: java, android, arraylist, compare

Let me give some code so you can see what I'm doing with the following java code for android. Say for example I have the following two classes, one extended from the other:

```
class MyClassOne {
    protected float x, y;
    MyClassOne(float x, float y) { 
        this.x = x; this.y=y;
    }
    public void printY(){
        System.out.print(y); 
    }
}

class MyClassTwo extends MyClassOne {
    protected String stringSpecificToThisClass;
    private long longSpecificTothisClass;
    MyClassTwo(float x, float y, String s, long l) {
        this.x=x; this.y=y; 
        this.longSpecificTothisClass= l; this.stringSpecificTothisClass=s;
    }
}
```

These classes are then initialized in the following way

```
private ArrayList<MyClassOne> mClassOne = new ArrayList<MyClassOne>();
private ArrayList<MyClassTwo> mClassTwo = new ArrayList<MyClassTwo>();
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    Random random = new Random(10);
    mClassOne.add(new MyClassOne(i*12, random.nextInt()));
    mClassTwo.add(new MyClassOne(i*11, random.nextInt()));
}
```

now, what I want to do is compare and sort ***both*** arraylists according to the value of y.

The way i do this for a single list is like so:

```
private Object[][] mSort(){
    Object[][] mSort = new Object[mClassOne.size()][2];
    for(int i = 0; i<mClassOne.size(); i++){
        mSort[i][0] = i;
        mSort[i][1] = mClassOne.get(i).y;
    }
    Arrays.sort(mSort, new Comparator<Object[]>(){
        @Override
        public int compare(Object[] obj1, Object[] obj2){
            Float comp1 = (Float)obj1[1]; Float comp2 = (Float) obj2[1];
            return comp1.compareTo(comp2);
        }
    });
    return mSort;
}

Object[][] mSort = mSort();
for(int i=0;i<mClassOne.size();i++){
    int z = (Integer)mSort[i][0];
    mClassOne.get(z).printY();
}
```

which could output something like this:

```
2, 4, 5, 6, 9
```

Hopefully the code above is clear enough so others can see what I'm trying to do; the question is:

"How could I combine both ArrayLists then sort them by their respective y value."

### The Answer I was looking for

```
ArrayList<MyClassOne> mTest = new ArrayList<MyClassOne>();
mTest.addAll(mClassOne);
mTest.addAll(mClassTwo);
Collections.sort(mTest, new Comparator<MyClassOne>(){
    @Override
    public int compare(MyClassOne obj1, MyClassTwo obj2) {
        return (int) (obj1.getY() - obj2.getY()); } 
    }
);
// mTest is now sorted, verified by ~ foreach(mTest) {print mTest.getY(); }
```

Comment: Maybe Im just slow today, but I am completely unable to understand your question. Your code seem rather confusing. Cant you explain what you are trying to achieve in words?

Comment: so for reference: ArrayList<MyClassOne> mTest = new ArrayList<MyClassOne>(); mTest.addAll(mClassOne); mTest.addAll(mClassTwo); Collections.sort(mTest, new Comparator<MyClassOne>(){ @Override public int compare(MyClassOne obj1, MyClassTwo obj2) { return (int) (obj1.getY() - obj2.getY()); } }); // mTest is now sorted, verified by ~ foreach(mTest) {print mTest.getY(); }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could use a `Comparator<MyClassOne>` which should be able to handle `MyClassTwo` instances as well, since `MyClassTwo` extends `MyClassOne`.

Just create a single `List<MyClassOne>`, add all elements of the other lists and sort.

In cases where the classes don't extend each other, introduce a common interface.

Comment: That, combined with using `Collections.sort` after dumping both lists into a single list parameterized with `MyClassOne`. The `Comparator` would require access to the `y` field, though.

Comment: @G_H you're right, I didn't see there's no getter for `y`. @Terry, please add that getter to `MyClassOne`.

Comment: mmm, don't have anything - still testing :)

Comment: I have accepted your answer. Thanks for the input both && @G_H